# Asp.net Identity Core db context and custom dbcontext in separate solutions, same database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

I am trying to achieve following architecture, where Asp.Net Core Identity Membership database context will be shared as own solution so I can use it in connection with custom DB context solution.

Why? I want to use Asp.Net Core Identity membership, without reinstalling and setting up for each different project. The question here is, if I have some dependencies with foreign keys inside of Asp_Net_Users table with any of my custom made tables in separate DBContext solution, how can I link them with membership tables?

So perfect scenario is on first migration to install membership tables into database, and then when I run migrations on API A db context inside same database, and I have some foreign keys with membership tables, it should link them in same database.

Items:

MVC project A
MVC project B
Asp.Net Core Identity Membership with DBContext
ApiA with DBContext
ApiB with DBContext

Architecture is like this:
[image]

Question is, how can I link custom dbcontext(i want to link custom table1 with asp_net_user from identity) which is in own solution, with identity dbcontext which is in own solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  My scenario is similar, but works backwards from yours.  I would like to share my custom DbContext with multiple Web Apps, but have the IdentityDbContext live in only one Web App (my FBA app).  I'd like to relate ApplicationUsers to entities in the custom dbcontext.